# Sitecore Powershell - List all child-items of a items with created date, created by and generate excel file

Tags: sitecore

I am using Sitecore Powershell and wrote a script to get all child-items of a items with "creation date" and "created by" field values.

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | Show-ListView -Property Name,"__Created By",__Created
```

its give correct result in list view but when i click on download excel file from ribbon. generated file don't give correct result. its give all fields in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of console are you using? I would suggest that you update the module to the latest version before we dig deeper into solving the problem by debugging it.

You can learn what version is running by using the Get-Host commandlet.

e.g., for me it looks like:

```
Name             : Sitecore Console Host 2.7.1.1646 on Windows PowerShell 4.0
Version          : 2.7.1.1646
InstanceId       : bfba97c5-b261-465f-b602-4b306d576423
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : pl-PL
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Cognifide.PowerShell.PowerShellIntegrations.Host.ScriptingHostPrivateData
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Updating to the version 2.7.5 fixed the problem. Thanks for using the Module!

Comment: For me it looks like:
Name             : Sitecore Console Host

Version          : 2.7.1.30555

InstanceId       : d47e6c57-666a-46b8-8257-0bc52c8f9afc

UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface

CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Cognifide.PowerShell.PowerShellIntegrations.Host.ScriptingHostPrivateData
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Comment: I wonder if you could update your PowerShell Extensions with the latest version (about to be release on Marketplace) https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/raw/master/Data/packages/Sitecore%20PowerShell%20Extensions-2.7.5.zip ? 
It should fix the problem for you.

Comment: its works for me, Thanks Adma ! for your suggestion and module.

Comment: Thanks for the question, and for using the module!